# one broker url with many topics in mqtt

Tags: java, mqtt

I have two topics and one broker URL. I need to publish to these two topics using one broker URL.

I did it with one broker URL and one topic. Then I  tried to do with two topics and write two subscriber class for each topic but when I run two subscriber classes one will shows connection lost.
Suggest some good examples to do this.

MQTTPublisher.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClientPersistence;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttDefaultFilePersistence;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttMessage;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttTopic;

public class MQTTPublisher {


static final String BROKER_URL = "tcp://localhost:1883";// public mosquitto
                                                        // server
static final String TOPIC = "iotm/ej";// Change according to your
                                            // application
static final String TOPIC1 = "iotm/stream1";

public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {
        // Creating new default persistence for mqtt client
        MqttClientPersistence persistence = new MqttDefaultFilePersistence(
                "/tmp");

        // mqtt client with specific url and client id
        MqttClient client1 = new MqttClient(BROKER_URL, "Publisher-ID",
                persistence);

        client.connect();

        MqttTopic myTopic = client1.getTopic(TOPIC);
        MqttTopic myTopic1 = client1.getTopic(TOPIC1);
        String msg = "AMMA!DEVI!dURGA";
         System.out.println("Enter the message to publish,Type quit to exit\n");
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new
         InputStreamReader(System.in));
         msg = br.readLine();
         while (!msg.equals("quit")) {
         myTopic.publish(new MqttMessage(msg.getBytes()));
         System.out.println("Message published on" + TOPIC);
         myTopic1.publish(new MqttMessage(msg.getBytes()));

         System.out.println("Message published on" + TOPIC1);
         msg = br.readLine();
         }
        myTopic.publish(new MqttMessage(msg.getBytes()));

        myTopic1.publish(new MqttMessage(msg.getBytes()));

        // client.disconnect();
    } catch (MqttException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

MQTTSubscriber.java

```
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttCallback;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttDefaultFilePersistence;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttDeliveryToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttMessage;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttTopic;

public class MQTTSubscriber {

static final String BROKER_URL = "tcp://localhost:1883";// public
// mosquitto server
static final String TOPIC = "iotm/ej"; // Change according to your



public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {
        // Creating new default persistence for mqtt client
        MqttDefaultFilePersistence persistence = new MqttDefaultFilePersistence(
                "/tmp");

        // mqtt client with specific url and a random client id
        MqttClient client1 = new MqttClient(BROKER_URL, "Subscriber-ID",
                persistence);
        client1.connect();
        System.out.println("Subscribing to topic '" + TOPIC + "' from "
                + client1.getServerURI());
        // Subscribing to specific topic
        client1.subscribe(TOPIC);

        // It will trigger when a new message is arrived
        MqttCallback callback = new MqttCallback() {
            @Override
            public void messageArrived(MqttTopic arg0, MqttMessage arg1)
                    throws Exception {
                System.out.println("Message:"
                        + new String(arg1.getPayload()));

            }

            @Override
            public void deliveryComplete(MqttDeliveryToken arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void connectionLost(Throwable arg0) {
                System.out.println("Connection lost");
            }
        };
        // Continue waiting for messages until the Enter is pressed
        client1.setCallback(callback);
        /*
         * System.out.println("Press <Enter> to exit"); try {
         * System.in.read(); } catch (IOException e) { // If we can't read
         * we'll just exit }
         */
        // client.disconnect();
        // System.out.println("Client Disconnected");

    } catch (MqttException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

}
```

MQTTSubscriber2.java

```
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttCallback;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttDefaultFilePersistence;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttDeliveryToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttMessage;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttTopic;

  public class MQTTSubscriber2 {


static final String BROKER_URL = "tcp://localhost:1883";// public
// mosquitto server
static final String TOPIC = "iotm/stream1"; 



public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {
        // Creating new default persistence for mqtt client
        MqttDefaultFilePersistence persistence = new MqttDefaultFilePersistence(
                "/tmp");

        // mqtt client with specific url and a random client id
        MqttClient client = new MqttClient(BROKER_URL, "Subscriber-ID",
                persistence);
        client.connect();
        System.out.println("Subscribing to topic '" + TOPIC + "' from "
                + client.getServerURI());
        // Subscribing to specific topic
        client.subscribe(TOPIC);

        // It will trigger when a new message is arrived
        MqttCallback callback = new MqttCallback() {
            @Override
            public void messageArrived(MqttTopic arg0, MqttMessage arg1)
                    throws Exception {
                System.out.println("Message:"
                        + new String(arg1.getPayload()));

            }

            @Override
            public void deliveryComplete(MqttDeliveryToken arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void connectionLost(Throwable arg0) {
                System.out.println("Connection lost");
            }
        };
        // Continue waiting for messages until the Enter is pressed
        client.setCallback(callback);
        /*
         * System.out.println("Press <Enter> to exit"); try {
         * System.in.read(); } catch (IOException e) { // If we can't read
         * we'll just exit }
         */
        // client.disconnect();
        // System.out.println("Client Disconnected");

    } catch (MqttException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post some sample code which shows the problem? Also it's not clear, but are you using 2 client instances? If so they will need different client ids

Comment: @hardillb : added my sample code.. actually i am new to mqtt so i just do this based on an example in net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running 2 separate instances of the subscriber code then they will both need different client ids. If you run 2 with the same then the first will be disconnected from the broker when the second connects.